# Browsing a WebSphere MQ Durable Subscription

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

here is my situation.

I want to have a browse function for messages pending on a durable subscription which is  using managed queues (so I can not access the subscription's queue directly).

If this was a queue, I would simply use something like

```
remoteDestination = session.QueueManager.AccessQueue(
                    remoteQueueName,
                    MQC.MQOO_BROWSE                 // request browse mode
                    + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING    // but not if MQM stopping
                    + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE              // request inquire permissions to read stats
                    );
```

However, on a durablesub'd topic, there is no available BROWSE flag

```
remoteDestination = session.QueueManager.AccessTopic(
                    remoteTopicName,
                    remoteTopicObject,                    
                    MQC.MQOO_BROWSE                 //can not use an MQOO option here!!!
                    + MQC.MQSO_CREATE                 // create the topic if not already created
                    + MQC.MQSO_ANY_USERID           // allow any user to reattach to this subscription in the future
                                                    // otherwise, only the user who created the subscription can reattach
                    + MQC.MQSO_ALTER                // create (or reattach) to subscription requesting rights to make changes
                    + MQC.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING    // if the server is shutting down, fail 
                    + MQC.MQSO_DURABLE              // the subscription is durable
                    + MQC.MQSO_MANAGED,             // the queue manager will create consup
                    "",                             // alternate user ID
                    subscriptionName                // name of the subscription
                );
```

Sooooo, I am simply wondering if this is possible? I'm guessing there must be SOME way for an app to tell what and how many messages its about to consume from a durable subscription before it re-attaches!?

Note that the purpose of all this is allow a service application to display to its interactive user all of the "pending" messages in its durable subscription in case of trouble shooting.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help out!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inquire on the subscription to obtain the name of the associated managed queue, then browse or inquire on that queue using normal methods.  You are correct that there is no browse API for a durable subscription.

Comment: Hey T.Rob. I never noticed your reply (it was some time after the question), but it did end up being the approach we took as well. So this is in fact the best answer in my opinion!